# How to adjust vertical spacing between text and equations in Word 2010 / MathType

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, mathtype

I'm trying to use Word 2010 for a text that has a lot of equations. I've managed to number and refer to the equations, but the vertical spacing between numbered equations and the surrounding text is too small:

[image]

How can I increase the vertical spacing between the text and the equations?

Comment: Edit paragraph settings.

Comment: Try SHIFT+ENTER after the lines of text, etc.

Comment: @Gryphoenix thanks! I'm a LaTex user, haven't used Word for ages.

Comment: @tomislav-maric - ha ha, no problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that SHIFT+ENTER after each line will get you what you need.